# Can someone explain this “à 13 ans”?

Tags: grammaire, sens, expressions-idiomatiques

*je viens juste de m'en rendre compte à 13 ans.*

This means *'I just realized it at 13'.*

I have no idea why? I read ***'I come just of me, it returns account at 13 years.'*** Which obviously makes no sense to me as is wrong.

Comment: A more accurate literal translation would be: "I just come to give back to myself an account of it"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Je viens [juste] de + V = I just V[past].

Se rendre compte [de + something/que + V] = to realize something, to understand something.

Je viens juste de me rendre compte [de X / que + V] = I just realized X, that V.

Here "en" refers to something previously discussed.

Comment: Wow. This is amazing. I have been studying so much vocabulary and verbs (1,600 words and 1,700 verbs known so far) and yet it never teaches you these things. Like the verb 'to come' and juste de together would translate as 'I just'.. how would you know that!? Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It makes sense if the person speaking is actually 13 years old...
could be translated as 'it's only now, at the age of 13, that I realize it'
= Je viens seulement de m'en rendre compte, à 13 ans.